# Repeat Macro For Specified Time Interval

Tags: excel, vba

I have four macros that I want to run every 10 minutes in a specified order. Currently I just set a reminder to run them, but would like to automate the process. Ideally I would love to have a separate macro that repeats all four macros (in order) every 10 mins.

I have tried adding `Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:10:00"), "Macro_Name"` at the end of the four macros. Issue is two of the macros take some time to process.

Also tried creating a separate Macro "Repeat_10mins", and building it using the `OnTime` function. Only seems to work once, and doesn't repeat (i.e, runs 10 mins after setting but does not repeat).

```
Sub Repeat_10mins

Workbooks("Book1.xlsm").RefreshAll

'Repeat Macro1
 Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue ("00:10:00"), "Macro1"

'Repeat Macro2
 Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue ("00:10:00"), "Macro2"

(etc for Macro 3/4)

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you attempted to run these via scheduling a task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create one more macro like this:

```
Sub Timer()

Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:10:00"), "operation"

End Sub
```

Where `operation` is the name of the macro you want to run every 10 minutes.

On the macro you have built you will need to add only one line at the end which is `Call Timer`.

Explanation: 
At the end of the macro `operation` it will call the macro `timer` which in 10 minutes will run `operation`.

Let me know if it works or if you need any more help.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much @wisniadj